# Symbol's function definition is void: pdf-tools-install after succesfull Installation with nor error messages

Tags: debugging, pdf-tools

I tried to install pdf-tools under emacs 24 and Ubunt 16.04, like I did it several times succesfully.

But now I get the error messages:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: pdf-tools-install
```

PDFs are still opened with the docview mode.

When I use M-x pdf-tools-install after Downloading from Melpa I get the message "Sever build succesfully".

Any ideas what's gone wrong?

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t`. Post the backtrace. Some code you are invoking  tries to invoke function `pdf-tools-install`, but the code that defines that function has not been loaded.

Comment: That function should be autoloaded by `package-initialize`.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to run that code before packages are initialized. Try adding (package-initialize) near the beginning of your init file, and definitely before trying to invoke pdf-tools-install

Answer (score 1):

(package-initialize) was missed in my init.el.

Thanks to all for your help!